# dotnet restore fails when runtime has centos.7.1-x64

Tags: .net-core

I have Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3. .Net Core 1.0.0-preview2
Visual Studio 2015 -> Create new project -> Web -> Asp.Net Core Web Application (.Net Core)
Restore & Compile works perfectly
Change project.json to remove type platform and add runtime

you can view project.json at https://gist.github.com/rohitshrivastava04/10dc4be2c06c1eb8a25ee89775e02105

I have checked my global.json is pointing to correct sdk, below is the global.json
{ "projects": [ "src", "test" ], "sdk": { "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121" } }

restore fails with below error

`Errors in c:\Users\007\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication5\src\WebApplication5\WebApplication5.xproj System.Diagnostics.Process 4.1.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Diagnostics.Process on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Globalization.Extensions 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Globalization.Extensions on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Net.NameResolution 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Net.NameResolution on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Net.Requests 4.0.11 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Net.Requests on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Net.Security 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Net.Security on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms 4.2.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates 4.1.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Reflection.Extensions 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Reflection.Extensions on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Security.Principal.Windows 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Security.Principal.Windows on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Collections 4.0.11 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Collections on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Diagnostics.Debug 4.0.11 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Diagnostics.Debug on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Globalization 4.0.11 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Globalization on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.IO 4.1.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Net.Primitives 4.0.11 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Net.Primitives on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Runtime.Extensions 4.1.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Runtime.Extensions on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Runtime.InteropServices 4.1.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Runtime.InteropServices on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Text.Encoding 4.0.11 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Text.Encoding on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Threading.Tasks 4.0.11 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Tasks on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Threading.Timer 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Timer on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO.FileSystem on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Console 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Console on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. Microsoft.Win32.Registry 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for Microsoft.Win32.Registry on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Net.Sockets on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Reflection 4.1.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Reflection on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Reflection.Primitives 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Reflection.Primitives on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Resources.ResourceManager 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Resources.ResourceManager on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Runtime 4.1.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Runtime on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. Microsoft.Win32.Primitives 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for Microsoft.Win32.Primitives on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Diagnostics.Tools on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Diagnostics.Tracing 4.1.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Diagnostics.Tracing on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Globalization.Calendars 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Globalization.Calendars on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.IO.Compression 4.1.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO.Compression on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Net.Http 4.1.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Net.Http on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Runtime.Handles on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. System.Text.Encoding.Extensions 4.0.11 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Text.Encoding.Extensions on .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with centos.7.1-x64. One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0 (centos.7.1-x64).`